# How can I get a Windows 2008 print server to deploy to child domains?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-domain, print-server

I am setting up a print server for our company that has a parent domain and 2 child domains. The print server is on the parent domain and I have no problems getting the print server to deploy printers through group policy to users on its own domain. The problem I am having is that it isn't deploying the printers to users that are in it's child domains.

Some other info that may help:

- I am not sharing or listing printers in the directory
- I have added `pushprinterconnections.exe` to the group policy login script

Does anything come to mind?